# Authenticating engines using Clearance in main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rails-engines, clearance

#### Context

I want to run several rails applications on the same server, by implementing them as engines in a main application. The main application should contain authentication logic, such as users and roles.

---

#### Problem

I am using **clearance**, by Thoughbot, for my user system, but when I want to authenticate an engine by using `before_action :require_login` in its controllers, I get the following error:

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError in MyEngine::PagesController#index. No route matches {:action => "new", :controller => "clearance/sessions"}`

I understand this is because the engine is looking for clearance controllers inside its namespace, but how do I get the engine to look in the main application? Is there an easy fix to this which is flexible enough to not be a hassle when adding new engines to the system?

#### Edit:

I have already tried inheriting from the main app ApplicationController, by doing

`class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trace the code in `lib/clearance/authorization.rb` to look for methods to override or configure.

In this case, it looks like you want to override `sign_in_url` so that the resulting URL points to your host app.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to engines, and am struggling with namespaces and how to override/change functionality. This was enough to find a solution ☺